# IndexOutOfBoundsException when adding to ArrayList using nested while loops

Tags: java, while-loop

I'm trying to create a program which reads a reads a file containing the amount of people in each school district in a state and outputs the total number of people, total number of children, and total number of children below the poverty line. There are 56 states but I can only get the output for 55.

I also tried putting `int i = 0` inside the first while loop but I just got a bunch of 0s.

```java
int i = 0; int j = 1;
        while (j <= Integer.parseInt( popInfo.get(popInfo.size() - 1).getStateCode() )) {
            int tPopCt = 0, cPopCt = 0, cPovPopCt = 0;

            while (popInfo.get(i).getStateCode().equals(String.format("%02d", j))) {
                tPopCt += Integer.parseInt(popInfo.get(i).getTotalPopulation());
                cPopCt += Integer.parseInt(popInfo.get(i).getChildPopulation());
                cPovPopCt += Integer.parseInt(popInfo.get(i).getChildPovertyPopulation());
                i++;
            }
            output.add(new Output(String.format("%02d", j), tPopCt, cPopCt, cPovPopCt));
            j++;
        }
```

I expected the last line of the output to start with 56 (the last StateCode) however I get an error. When I set the first while loop to `j < ...` instead of `j <= ...`, I get `55 5956920 963445 157356` which is correct but does not include 56.

Please help. TY

### Edit

The error message and stack trace...

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.IndexOutOfBoundsException: Index 13486 out of bounds for length 13486
at java.base/jdk.internal.util.Preconditions.outOfBounds(Preconditions.java:64)
at java.base/jdk.internal.util.Preconditions.outOfBoundsCheckIndex(Preconditions.java:70)
at java.base/jdk.internal.util.Preconditions.checkIndex(Preconditions.java:248)
at java.base/java.util.Objects.checkIndex(Objects.java:372)
at java.base/java.util.ArrayList.get(ArrayList.java:458)
at Poverty.<init>(Poverty.java:35)
at Poverty.main(Poverty.java:70)
```

Comment: _however I get an error_ Perhaps you could post the details of the error you are getting?

Comment: Exception in thread "main" java.lang.IndexOutOfBoundsException: Index 13486 out of bounds for length 13486
 at java.base/jdk.internal.util.Preconditions.outOfBounds(Preconditions.java:64)
 at java.base/jdk.internal.util.Preconditions.outOfBoundsCheckIndex(Preconditions.java:70)
 at java.base/jdk.internal.util.Preconditions.checkIndex(Preconditions.java:248)
 at java.base/java.util.Objects.checkIndex(Objects.java:372)
 at java.base/java.util.ArrayList.get(ArrayList.java:458)
 at Poverty.<init>(Poverty.java:35)
 at Poverty.main(Poverty.java:70)

Comment: You can [edit] your post and add the stack trace rather than put it in a comment. Never mind, I did it for you. (You're welcome.)

Answer (score 1):

You should consider redesigning your program.
You didn't wrote what is the type of elements in `popInfo` collection, so let's call it `PopData`. 
Maybe you should use one for-each loop instead of nested while loops.
In this case structure of your program could look like (extract values from `data` variable which represents one record of data in your collection):

```
int globalTPopCt = 0;
int globalCPopCt = 0;
int globalCPovPopCt = 0;
for(PopData data : popInfo) {
    int state = Integer.parseInt(data.getStateCode());
    //local counters
    int localTPopCt = Integer.parseInt(data.getTotalPopulation());
    int localCPopCt = Integer.parseInt(data.getChildPopulation());
    int localCPovPopCt = Integer.parseInt(data.getChildPovertyPopulation());
    //global (cumulated) counters
    globalTPopCt += localTPopCt;
    globalCPopCt += localCPopCt;
    globalCPovPopCt += localCPovPopCt;

    output.add(new Output( ... ));
}
```